# Mysql query with '>=', '<=' statements in java page is returning null while query working fine in MySQL Console, Why?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I tried the same query in the MySQL console of wamp server with the same values returned by another query in the function and returning results but it is returning null in the java, why?
I am using eclipse and tomcat version 6, Below is my code:-

```
    public String startpgm(String x){

        String np       = null;
        String North    = null;
        String Wb_SWLat = null;
        String Wb_SWLon = null;
        String Wb_NELat = null;
        String Wb_NELon = null;

        String qryWb = "select SW_lat, SW_lon, NE_lat, NE_lon from tbl_zones where zone='west'";

//      String qrywest = "select priority from tbl_vcl";

        String qrywest = "select priority from tbl_vcl where latitude >=? and latitude <=? and longitude >=? and longitude<=?";

        try {
            Statement stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();

        ResultSet Wb=stmt.executeQuery(qryWb);//storing the result into result set
        while(Wb.next()){ // looping through the resultset

            Wb_SWLat=Wb.getString("SW_lat");
            Wb_NELat=Wb.getString("NE_lat");
            Wb_SWLon=Wb.getString("SW_lon");            
            Wb_NELon=Wb.getString("NE_lon");

            System.out.println("DBSWlat:"+Wb_SWLat);
            System.out.println("DBNElat:"+Wb_NELat);
            System.out.println("DBSWLon:"+Wb_SWLon);
            System.out.println("DBNELon:"+Wb_NELon);
        }



        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(qrywest);// creating statement on the db connection for executing query

        ps.setString(1, Wb_SWLat);
        ps.setString(2, Wb_SWLon);
        ps.setString(3, Wb_NELat);
        ps.setString(4, Wb_NELon);

        ResultSet rsWest= ps.executeQuery();//storing the result into result set
//      System.out.println("test");
//      System.out.println("DBrset:"+rsWest);       

        while(rsWest.next()){ // looping through the resultset

            np=rsWest.getString("priority");
            System.out.println("np:"+np);
        }




        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        North=np;
        System.out.println("DB:"+North);


                    return North ;
        }
```

np is returning null, when i remove the conditions such as "where latitude >=? and latitude <=? and longitude >=? and longitude<=?" the query is working fine. I had used the same conditions in another project without any issue. What is the issue with the "<=", ">=" conditions in here?

Comment: Did you try debugging? What are the actual values being assigned?

Comment: @shmosel select priority from tbl_vcl where latitude >=9.994042 and latitude <=9.994195 and longitude >=76.356653 and longitude<=76.357181;

Comment: @shmosel I tried everything i can... The result returned from MySQL console is 2 with column name priority. while null is returned in java page

Comment: What about @nimrodm's answer?

Comment: @shmosel idk, how to solve this

Comment: You just need to reorder the parameters,

Comment: @shmosel how it has to be?

Comment: 1 - Wb_SWLat, 2 - Wb_NELat, 3 - Wb_SWLon, 4 - Wb_NELon. Additionally, it's a bit weird that you handle it as strings, not doubles/longs or some numeric type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ordering of the parameters in the prepared statement is different than what you use in the `setString` calls (lat/lat/long/long vs lat/long/lat/long).

Comment: Thanks You Very Much :)